# Lightning symbol with LuaTex

Tags: luatex

I'm trying to use the lightning symbol ↯ in my document. I use `luatex`. If I understand correctly I do *not* need the command

```
\unicode{x21af}
```

but I can write ↯ directly in my document. My problem is that the symbol does not appear in the generated pdf. Thus, I guess, the symbol is not contained in the font used in the pdf.

> If I have no error, how to I influence the chosen font? I should find a font with the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}    
(↯)    
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be some of the necessary (or all of the) font package(s) pretaining to that particular font class is missing?

Comment: @Raaja, this is a good point, but then 1) how do I find a font having this symbol, or the texlive package with it? 2) why more people [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/305879/322402) say of using it, without specifying any special condition?

Comment: for #1 I really don't know. #2 could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: for #2 I mean that the user is using `\unicode{x21af}` because he is using latex and not luatex; but he does not specify that he need some special package (containing the font) for the special lighting symbol. He got +9, that is, other 9 people got it working without adding a comment on some specialties.

Comment: in [#1] for  example, to look up font/package pretaining to a particular symbol you can look for instance in http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/stmaryrd-symbols.pdf. Note that this is just one example of a huge ecosystem of symbols :)

Comment: Which package defines the macro called `\unicode`?

Comment: On my system I see that character in "Arial Unicode MS"...

Comment: @Raaja, very good! I installed `texlive-stmaryrd`, added `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` and now `\lightning` gives me the needed symbol

Comment: @PeptideChain Great! next time have a sneak-peek into the log file to have a brief outlook over the problem.

Comment: See https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21af/fontsupport.htm to find fonts that support the character.

Comment: @PeptideChain, a side note : for such questions, you can try [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), very useful tool !

Comment: @Thérèse very interesting link

Comment: @BambOo unbelivable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you guess, it's just a matter of choosing a font containing the glyph. You do this using `fontspec`. (Update to use `\newunicodechar` courtesy of @egreg.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newfontfamily\symbola{Symbola}
\newcommand{\downzigzagarrow}{\begingroup\symbola ↯\endgroup}
\newunicodechar{↯}{\downzigzagarrow}
\begin{document}
Filler text ↯ Filler text
\end{document}
```

[image: down zig zag arrow symbol]

Comment: You can accompany this with `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and `\newunicodechar{↯}{\downzigzagarrow}` after defining `\downzigzagarrow` so it's possible to use `↯` directly in the document.

Comment: @egreg, no way. I never knew that.

Comment: I know the package, guess why. `;-)`